# What are the max dimensions that should be used for showing facebook photos?

Tags: facebook

I am grabbing the photo's of my user's friends on my site. And, the photos of the friends look very dull, and photos seem to have a very low resolution.

1. How can I make sure that the photos are sharp ? Do I need to do any post processing ?
2. What are the max dimensions that should be used for showing photos ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're grabbing profile thumbnail, it's because they get resized when you upload them to Facebook.  Facebook does this automatically.  If you want higher quality photos, you need to use a different API method than the the one used to get profile photos:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

I'd suggest "Photos" or "Photo albums" method.

*EDIT* The actual dimensions for a profile photo are 50x50.  If you try to display them larger than this, you're going to get loss.  Non vector graphics can only contain so much data per pixel.